# loopMIDI installation error

Tags: drivers, installation

Downloadable here http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html

So I have an issue and it's not the installer it's something with the "driver" named teVirtualMIDI and I don't really know much about how to fix it yet, I might need to deinstall the driver. It still shows up in `driverquery` typed in CMD though.

[image]

This is the part where it fails. I'veused the log file to see where that file gets saved at, found it opened it up with the window above but it says, it doesn't work.

When I hit okay, this happens

[image]

When I hit cancel, this appears

[image]

The log says `Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.`

What can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by manually removing the Source List for the program `teVirtualMIDI64` and `loopMIDI`.